# Symfony container, register method vs setdefinition

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

What's the point having these 2 different but having same meaning of methods. Is 1 suppose to be used in different place or what?

At moment i've watched knpuniversity videos and learned to do it via setdefinition, new definition way in the config.

```
public function register($id, $class = null)
{
    return $this->setDefinition($id, new Definition($class));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just *syntax sugar*. In Symfony there are usually 3 ways to do one thing.

1. First one is to get the job done

   ```
   $this->register('SomeClass')
   ```
2. Seconds is clear and direct

   ```
   $this->setDefinition('SomeClass', new Definition('SomeClass'));
   ```
3. Third allows you to do complicated things.

I prefer the 1st one, since it often leads to an even simpler way eventually.

```
# services.yaml
services:
    App\:
        resource: ../src
```

This will register all services from `/src` directory